# How to solve transform.position assign attempt for is not valid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I using unity and working on Kinect 360 is the version 1 , I create new scene and am working on 2D space also I create UI button in the scene center and one other UI button but I modify it to be like small circle and I named it cursor 
now I want to move the cursor with my right hand wish will detect by Kinect 
so I fall in that error which is

```
{
transform.position assign attempt for 'cursor' is not valid .Input position    is{-Infinity,-777756757673984982383290000000000000000000000,0,0} 
}
```

my code here

```
void Update () {

    KinectManager manager = KinectManager.Instance;

    if (DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders != null)
    {
        if (!isInited)
        {
            isInited = true;
            initialPosition = new Vector2((DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position.x + 50) * 19.2f, (DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position.y + 50) * 10.8f);//, DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position.z);
        }

        Vector2 newPos = new Vector2((DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position.x + 50) * 19.2f - offstX, (DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position.y + 50) * 10.8f - offstY) - initialPosition;//, DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position.z) - initialPosition;
        Debug.Log(DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("not joint colliders");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello everyBody I found the solution it is

```
public int offstX= 937;
public int offstY= 520;

bool isInited=false;
void Update() {

    uint playerID;
    if(manager != null){
        playerID = manager.GetPlayer1ID();
    }else{ playerID = 0; }

    if(playerID <= 0) {
        //reset all the position to the initial values 
        if (transform.position != initialPosition) {
            transform.position = initialPosition;
        }
        //reset all the rotation to the initial values 
        if (transform.rotation != initialRotation)
        {
            transform.rotation = initialRotation;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bones.Length; i++)
        {
            bones[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            bones[i].transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            bones[i].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            if (SkeletonLine)
            {
                lines[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    //set the user position in space 
    Vector3 positionPointMan = manager.GetUserPosition(playerID);
    */
    float initialXposition = transform.localPosition.x;
    float initialYposition = transform.localPosition.y;
    float nextXposition=0;
    float nextYposition=0;
    KinectManager manager = KinectManager.Instance; // call the Kinect instance

    if (DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders != null)
    {
        if (manager.Player1Calibrated && isInited == false)
        {
            isInited = true;
            Debug.Log("Kinect See Your hand");
            transform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
            nextXposition = transform.localPosition.x;
            nextYposition = transform.localPosition.y;
            if (initialXposition != nextXposition && initialYposition != nextYposition)
            {
                Debug.Log("I moved the cursor the the initial pisition");
            }
            else
                Debug.Log("Sorry I didn't translate the cursor");
        } else if (manager.Player1Calibrated && isInited == true)
        {
            float XvalueAre = DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.x * 192.0f + 184430.4f;
            float YvalueAre = DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.y *108.0f + 58832.1f;


        Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(XvalueAre - offstX, YvalueAre - offstY);// - initialPosition ,DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.position.z) - initialPosition;
            Debug.Log("Your Hand X position => " + DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.x);
            Debug.Log("Your Hand Y position => " + DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.y);
            Debug.Log("Your Converted Hand X position => " + XvalueAre);
            Debug.Log("Your Converted Hand Y position => " + YvalueAre);
            transform.position = newPos;

        }





     }
    else
        Debug.Log("Erreur remplir joints colliders ");

}
```